# How to post multiple files (images) using Jersey Web service.?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

Hi I am new to Restful web service.

My Goal is to create multiple user account's in a single request.

I am choosing Jersey API to create a web service.

This WS will create multiple user's account.  Each user account was associated with an avatar (Profile picture).  I am sending the user information with avatar (The avatar file was encoded into string format using Base64 encoder).

My question is, If the request has many number of users, and each user is associated with bigger size of avatar, Is Restful web service can handle these request?

Also the Request data size in the restful webservice is limited?

Please Suggest me to create a better web service in Jersey API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing avatars in message body you should look at [Jersey Multipart support](http://aruld.info/handling-multiparts-in-restful-applications-using-jersey/) - it will allow you to stream large files to your restful service. Another plus - you'll not need Base64 encoding anymore.

Comment: Is it possible to send multiple files at a time, also need to associate a file to a user.  I tried this, but I am unable find how to send multiple files, and associate file to a user.  Then I choose Base64 to encode the Image into string format, and send this through JSON.

Comment: You can send as many parts (and files of course) as you wish. You can establish link between file and user by filename for example. Yo can obtain file metadata as mentioned in this example: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Answer (score 2):

I can achieve this by doing form submit instead of preparing the object in JSON format.

```
@Path("/upload")
public class MultipleFiles
{
    private static final String FILE_UPLOAD_PATH = "/Users/arun_kumar/Pictures";
    private static final String CANDIDATE_NAME = "candidateName";
    private static final String SUCCESS_RESPONSE = "Successful";
    private static final String FAILED_RESPONSE = "Failed";

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/multipleFiles")
    public String registerWebService(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String responseStatus = SUCCESS_RESPONSE;        
        String candidateName = null;

        //checks whether there is a file upload request or not
        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        {
            final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            final ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            try
            {
                /*
                 * parseRequest returns a list of FileItem
                 * but in old (pre-java5) style
                 */
                final List items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);

                if (items != null)
                {
                    final Iterator iter = items.iterator();

                    while (iter.hasNext())
                    {
                        final FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                        final String itemName = item.getName();
                        final String fieldName = item.getFieldName(); 
                        final String fieldValue = item.getString();

                        if (item.isFormField())
                        {
                            candidateName = fieldValue;
                            System.out.println(" Name: " + fieldName + ", Value: " + fieldValue);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                final File savedFile = new File(FILE_UPLOAD_PATH + File.separator
                                         + itemName);
                                System.out.println(" Saving the file: " + savedFile.getName());
                                item.write(savedFile);                                
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileUploadException fue)
            {
                responseStatus = FAILED_RESPONSE;
                fue.printStackTrace();                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                responseStatus = FAILED_RESPONSE;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }        

        System.out.println("Returned Response Status: " + responseStatus);

        return responseStatus;
    }
}
```

Reference: [Jersey REST Web Service to Upload Multiple Files](http://crispcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/jersey-rest-web-service-to-upload-multiple-files/)